# Extract count of a string in log file using grep

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I want to get a count of exceptions in error log file of current date. below is log snippet

```
10.01.2017 14:03:15.517 *Error* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)

10.01.2017 14:03:15.516 *INFO* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)

09.01.2017 14:03:15.514 *INFO* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message  at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: For input string: "true"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
```

If i run the following grep command it gives me the result

```
$ grep -c $(date +"%d.%m.%Y") error.log
```

But when i'm trying to search it further using 'Exception' keyword it doesn't work. Below is the command

```
$ grep -c $(date +"%d.%m.%Y") error.log | grep 'Exception'
```

secondly another thing is i want to get the count of same exception line for this i'm using this command

```
$ grep  $(date +"%d.%m.%Y") error.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
```

But in excepted out i'm getting "1" "1" count for both line of 10 jan date because the millisecond(14:03:15.517 , 14:03:15.516) value is different. Is there any way through which i can skip this second value and find the line count

output:-

```
 1 10.01.2017 14:03:15.517 *Error* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
      1 10.01.2017 14:03:15.516 *Error* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
```

Expected output :-

```
2 10.01.2017 14:03:15 *Error* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: _Because_ the line containing the string `exception` is the next line matching your current date

Comment: So how can i get it using a command in linux

Comment: `.` in a regexp regpresents any character so if you're trying to grep for a date like `10.01.2017`, that will actually match against any string like `010201320175`. You need to escape the `.`s or use `-F` for string matching instead of regexp matching and consider adding additional constructs to avoid other partial matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `GNU grep` use the the `-A` flag to show lines matching *after* the given pattern, i.e.

```
grep -A 2 "$(date +"%d.%m.%Y")" file 
10.01.2017 14:03:15.517 *Error* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
--
10.01.2017 14:03:15.516 *INFO* [10.207.11.183 [1481704390201] POST /bin/flipkart/cart.GetCart.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.cxf.services.StockServiceService.StockServicePort.StockService Inbound Message at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
```

The above command shows only the next two lines following the `date`, now to get the count, use

```
grep -A 2 "$(date +"%d.%m.%Y")" file | grep -c "Exception"
2
```

Using a combination of two `awk`

```
awk -v dateToSearch="$(gdate +"%d.%m.%Y")" '$0 ~ dateToSearch{line[NR+2]}NR in line' file | awk -F'[:.]' '{unique[$4]++}END{for (i in unique) print i, unique[i]}' 
NumberFormatException 2
```

I will break-down the logic used in `Awk` for a better understanding.

- The input lines are parsed one line at a time in `awk`, to search on today's date, am using a variable with the `-v` flag (`awk` specific), and setting it to today's date.
- The body of the command `$0 ~ dateToSearch{line[NR+2]}NR in line` does the following; the `$0` represents the entire line and a `regEx` pattern match is done with the `~` operator to match the lines containing the today's date. Once matched the commands within `{}` are executed. Which simply mean, print the 2nd line after the pattern match (similar to `grep -A 2 ..`). `NR` is a special variable in `awk` which keep tracks of the record number (line number) as and when the file is processed. So when a pattern is matched, `NR` is set to that line and hence `NR+2` prints the 2nd line after match.
- The pipelined `awk`, i.e. after `| awk ..` could be avoided and clubbed to make a single `awk` which could make the command complex. So what basically the second part does is, `-F'[:.]'` sets the input field separator to either the occurrence of a `:` or `.`, so that the fields/columns can be accessed via individual numbers (e.g. like `$1`, `$2`, etc).
- So to track the unique count of exceptions, am creating a hash-table using an array with the exception name (`$4` in the line) as the index and incrementing the occurrence of the exception, as it is seen. So once all the lines are processed, the array contains all exception types with their counts.
- The `END{}` clause in `awk` gets to run after all the lines are processed, so using it to print the count and the unique exception identifier.

Comment: Hi Inian, Thanks it works . Can you please give some idea about second part of this question. i.e secondly another thing is i want to get the count of same exception line for this i'm using this command

$ grep  $(date +"%d.%m.%Y") error.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
But in excepted out i'm getting "1" "1" count for both line of 10 jan date because the millisecond(14:03:15.517 , 14:03:15.516) value is different. Is there any way through which i can skip this second value and find the line count

Comment: Can you update question how exactly you want the output to be?

Comment: @user2142786: You want the exception count to be independent of today's date?

Comment: No i don't want it to be independent of today's date. i want the count of unique exception of today's date and exception text.

Comment: $ awk -v dateToSearch="$(date +"%d.%m.%Y")" '$0 ~ dateToSearch{line[NR+2]}NR in line' error.log | awk -F'[:.]' '{unique[$4]++}END{for (i in unique) print i, unique[i]}' it would be great if you can explain me how this command work As i'm new in shell script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132826/discussion-between-inian-and-user2142786).

Comment: The above commands will fail given various inputs since they're doing a regexp comparison where the `.`s in the date are wildcards and they're matching across a whole line instead of just the first field. It's also not necessary to create pipes of multiple commands to do this, one simple awk script will do the job robustly (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41576301/1745001).

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do what you're trying to do is with awk in paragraph mode (i.e. blank-line separated chunks of text courtesy of `RS=<null>`):

```
$ awk -v date="$(date +"%d.%m.%Y")" -v RS= '$1==date && /Exception/{c++} END{print c+0}' file
2
```

Note that there is no chance of false matches on the date with this approach since we're using an exact match and a string comparison on the first field.